# why can't I remove some controls from storyboard - Xcode

Tags: xcode4.2

I added a Navigation Bar manually, it doesn't even have a navigationController. Initially I had hard time adding it, but now I have hard time deleting it.
[image]

I tried all combinations of delete, shift+delete, ctrl+delete and more. Nothing works, I really don't want it there. It actually creates 2 bars.

Last resort would be to delete the viewcontroller and create a new one. But I'm curious on why it happens. I don't know if it's just me, but this new Xcode seems more buggy. It crashes frequently.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I found the issue, I previously did an Embed-in NavigationController which I didn't notice, my bad. My storyboard is kinda cluttered right now, that's the reason it went unnoticed. I should organize it asap.

Answer (score 11):

The way to remove `Navigation Item` in this case is to right click your controller, find `relationship` outlet and unplug the associated navigation controller. After this is done, you can safely remove the `Navigation Item`.

Comment: I can see exactly why they have this functionality but it is so difficult to realise why it just doesn't work when connected to a navigation controller

Answer (score 0):

@Alexi's answer, to delete the outlet reference, did not work for me, after deleting the outlet reference I next deleted the `UINavigationViewController's` `Relationship Segue`, to the `UIViewController` that had a `UINavigationItem` I could not delete.

Then I could delete the Navigation Item in my UIViewController.

Finally, I added the `Relationship Segue` in Xcode 7 like so:

1. In the Storyboard, Control drag from `UINavigationController` to the `UIViewController`
2. Select `root view controller` under the `Relationship Seque` header

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am new to this, nothing seemed to work. Finally, I opened the file main.storyboard and deleted everything related to navigation. That worked for my (little)project but not sure if such brute force method will work in general.